# Why would I not be able to access a method from an extended nested class?

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes, quickfixj

I'm attempting to access a method inside a nested class that my class extends.
Specifically, it's the `getSenderSubID()` method in `quickfix.fix42.Message.Header`.
[image]

`public class ExecutionReport extends Message`, and the constructor of `Message` is:

```
protected Message(int[] fieldOrder) {
        super(fieldOrder);
        header = new Header(this);
        trailer = new Trailer();
        
        getHeader().setField(new BeginString("FIX.4.2"));
            
    }
```

The nested `Header` class is:

```
public static class Header extends quickfix.Message.Header {

        static final long serialVersionUID = 20050617;

        public Header(Message msg) {
            // JNI compatibility
        }
```

and the method inside there I want to access is:

```
    public quickfix.field.SenderSubID getSenderSubID() throws FieldNotFound {
        return get(new quickfix.field.SenderSubID());
    }
```

To me all of this looks like I should be able to use this method, but it's apparent that I cannot. How could this be?

I double checked that all classes were in `package quickfix.fix42;` and there were no method overrides in `ExecutionReport`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Not sure what FIX version you're using; I'll say you're using FIX44 for the purposes of this answer.  You can adjust accordingly.)*

I think `getHeader()` is returning a `quickfix.Message.Header` and not a `quickfix.fix44.Message.Header`.  Only the latter has `getSenderSubID()`.

Try casting `quickfix.Message.Header` to `quickfix.fix44.Message.Header`.